# Resizing UIView based on the subview loaded from xib file

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have xib file whose height can dynamically change as it contains labels of multiple lines. I need add this view as a subview of uiview that is defined in my view controller.

```
let settlementDetailsContentView = SettlementDetailsView.instanceFromNib(nibNamed: NibConstants.SettlementDetailsViewNib)
settlementDetailsContentView.frame = settlementDetailsView.bounds
settlementDetailsView.addSubview(settlementDetailsContentView)
```

Here settlementDetailsContentView contains the view that is designed in Interface 
builder. settlementDetailsView is the view defined in my view controller whose height constraint is greater or equal to zero.

Code below is the function that returns the view based on the nib name

```
 class func instanceFromNib(nibNamed : String) -> SettlementDetailsView
 {
     return UINib(nibName: nibNamed, bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! SettlementDetailsView
 }
```

The problem with what I did is that view below the settlementdetailsview overlaps on this since the view height is not resizing based on the subview.

> This is how the UI looks.Claim documents overlapping on
>   settlementDetails view.

[image: This is how the view looks.]

> This is how the uiview should look like

[image]

Comment: Try adding `settlementDetailsView.setNeedsLayout()` after adding `settlementDetailsContentView` as subview.

Comment: You could add the height constraint programmatically when subview is added

Comment: @laxmankhanal setNeedsLayout doesn't work

Comment: @chirag90 how could I find the height of the view since it's dynamic and some view sinside xib file may be hidden based on some condition

Comment: Try setting the maskToBound property of `settlementDetailsView` to true.
Also verify if the frame of `settlementDetailsView`  changes

Comment: @HansFehrmann there is no such property called maskToBound for the UIView.

Comment: @PrabuRaj My bad, try `settlementDetailsView.layer.maskToBounds`

Comment: @HansFehrmann bounds of settlementDetailsView remains the same. It does not change. And setting maskToBounds to true doesn't work.

Comment: @PrabuRaj Do you want to `settlementDetailsView ` wrap over `settlementDetailsContentView `? (ie, that the superview  shrink to the size of the subview)

Comment: in which method you are adding subview?

Comment: in my own method.. I created a method named initializeview() and this method is invoked from view controller from viewDidLoad() method

Comment: @HansFehrmann I want the superview(settlementDetailsView) to grow as much as the subview(settlementDetailsContetnView)

Comment: @PrabuRaj - Is "Claim Documents" (and the full gray box) supposed to show below the "Transferred Date" label? Can you show an image of how you *want* it to look?

Comment: @DonMag yeah that was the intended view.

Comment: @DonMag The gray box should appear below the transfered date label which is contained in settlementdetails view

Comment: @DonMag I have added the image that you asked for.

Comment: @PrabuRaj - ok... if you are adding `settlementDetailsContentView` as a subview of `settlementDetailsView`, is the "Transferred Date" label *also* a subview of `settlementDetailsView`? If so, are you using the bottom constraint of the label to determine the height of `settlementDetailsView`? Or... are the labels in *another* View that is a subview of `settlementDetailsView`?

Comment: @DonMag from **account number** label to the **transfered date** is settlementDetailsContentView which is the subview of settlementDetailsView

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not changing the frame of `settlementDetailsView`. In the following code

```
let settlementDetailsContentView = SettlementDetailsView.instanceFromNib(nibNamed: NibConstants.SettlementDetailsViewNib)
settlementDetailsView.addSubview(settlementDetailsContentView)
settlementDetailsContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
settlementDetailsContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: settlementDetailsView.topAnchor).isActive = true
settlementDetailsContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: settlementDetailsView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
settlementDetailsContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: settlementDetailsView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
settlementDetailsContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: settlementDetailsView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

You constraint that the subview grow to the full size of the superView or that the superView shrink to the size of the subview (this depend on the constraints of the superview and the hugging/compression of boths, but should give you the desire effect).

See the [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html) reference

**EDIT**

Now that you posted how it should look like this, the following code accomplish that:

```
let superView = settlementDetailsView.superview!
let settlementDetailsContentView = SettlementDetailsView.instanceFromNib(nibNamed: NibConstants.SettlementDetailsViewNib)
superview.addSubview(settlementDetailsContentView)
settlementDetailsContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
settlementDetailsContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: settlementDetailsView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
settlementDetailsContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
settlementDetailsContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
settlementDetailsContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Note that if `settlementDetailsView` have a bottom constraint to its superView, you should deactivate it.

Comment: Still the same problem.. UIView looks the same as in screenshot above.

Comment: As a test, try changing by hand the `settlementDetailsView` frame. Also check that `settlementDetailsContentView` has the same frame of the superView. Maybe the view is with a clear color

Comment: what should I set the settlementDetails view frame to? And what do you mean by the view is with a clear color? do you mean the background?